# How can I render to my View the Live count of Enqueued data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm Creating A Queue System, my problem is I need to render to the view the live count of my Queue.

Here is my control for enqueuing my incoming customers :

```
public ActionResult SetQueueInfo([Bind(Include = "QueueId,Name,QueueNumber,ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLetter")] MyQueue queue/*, int? id,string Name, string QueueNumber, string ServiceLetter, int ServiceId*/, int? id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MyQueue.todayQueue.Enqueue(queue);
        MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
        db.Queues.Add(queue);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(queue);
    }
    return View();
}
```

And here is my control for Dequeuing them :

```
public ActionResult BtnNext()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
    MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
    TempData["QueueItem"] = first;
    return PartialView("_queuenumber");
}
```

Now I'm using an Ajax Button so when ever I click the `BtnNext()` A single portion of my page will update.

How can I render the `Count()` whenever someone Enqueue or Dequeue like A live data.

I want a portion of my page that is Live whenever someone Enqueue or Dequeue

Answer (score 0):

You could use SignalR for that :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

But it required implementation listeners for client and server side.